# What is more resource saving: lodash deepEqual or creating a new object every time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, lodash

I have a complex heme object that contains a few nested objects and based on these variables I'm creating a new style object in the react components on each re-rerender. Basically this generated style shouldn't change during the runtime. I need to have an access to the theme during its first creation so I can't move it outside of component and use hardcoded theme variables. It must be created during the runtime (I didn't find any other way).

I don't like when the object creates on each re-render so I'd like to do it only once and re-create only if the theme values has been changed. Lodash memo didn't help somehow
so I would like to use **isEqual** to check if the theme was changed and re-create the style object.

But I'm not sure if the isEqual will be better in the case of resources instead of just a simple creating a new object because of *deep objects comparison* and it could take some time till the algorithm traverse the whole objects and compare each part of them. Isn't it?

What way is better regarding performance?

for ex.
Theme:

```
theme: {
 color: 'black',
 bg : { color: 'yellow' }
 ... so on
}

const styleCreator = (theme) => { 
     color: theme.bg.color
   }

// COMPONENT
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  // Here I want to save the old theme somewhere
  //  and compare it with the new one by isEqual
  // and only if they are different - create a new style
  const style = styleCreator(props.theme)
  return <h1 style={style} ></h1>
}
```

Comment: Considering the React architecture (which utilizes the «shallow comparison» style), `isEqual` is no-op. Instead you need to investigate why `memo` doesn't work as expected and consider using [React.useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) instead. Probable reasons: 1) `props.theme` is changed on every render - parents need memoization too, 2) you create the memoized function inside `MyComponent` - use `useMemo` instead. Please provide your code that uses `memo`.

Comment: Can you show us how the `theme` is changed?